# How do you center a box inside of a row which then goes into a list box (GTK+3 in C)

Tags: c, gtk

I have 5 different labels that are to go inside of a horizontal box, all labels are marked up and have the text resized using Pango. The box is then added to a row that is added to a list box.

I'm wondering how I am supposed to center the text, doesn't matter which element, as long as it is centered it's fine. I've tried multiple things like set_center_widget.

I'm writing my code in C.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used gtk_widget_set_hexpand (label, TRUE);